# How to delete a post completely

Tags: discussion

Suppose, by mistake, I posted some confidential information in a post (both question and answer). How can I delete the post so even moderators and users with enough reputation cannot view the post?

For example, I have seen some posts with API keys and credentials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*You* can't. Moderators have a redaction tool to delete the confidential information *specifically* - it doesn't delete the post totally though, just lets you remove the information.

Generally try not to. If you messed up, flag explaining what *exactly* needs removing.